# Почему не работает querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript

Так работает только с `getElementById`, но мне нужно поиск по классам:

```
function animateValue(selector, start, end, duration) {
    var range = end - start;
    var current = start;
    var increment = end > start? 1 : -1;
    var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
    var obj = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        current += increment;
        obj.innerHTML = current;
        if (current == end) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, stepTime);
}
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll(...)[0]`

Comment: ничего не понял. 
 var obj = document.querySelectorAll(selector)[0]; Не работает

Comment: Какой у вас selector и как вы определяете что не работает?

Comment: А констоль что говорит (`console.log(document.querySelectorAll(selector))`)?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` наверно перебрать надо

Answer (score 1):

Немного можно поколдовать:

```js
var test1 = {selector: ".bubu", start: 100, end: -100, durationSec: 10}
var test2 = {selector: ".bubu", index: 2, end: 200}
var test3 = {selector: ".bubu", index: 3, end: 100, durationSec: 20}
var test4 = {selector: "#bubu", start: 100, end: 200, durationSec: 100}
var test5 = {selector: "#moo", end: 1}
var test6 = {selector: ".moo", index: 15, end: 1}

animateValue( test1 );
animateValue( test2 );
animateValue( test3 );
animateValue( test4 );
animateValue( test5 );
animateValue( test6 );


function animateValue( obj ) { 
  var select = obj.selector;  
  var current = (obj.start || 0); // Если старт не указан - счет начнется с нуля.
  var end = obj.end;
  var index = Number( obj.index ) || "";
  
  var range = end - current; 
  var duration = obj.durationSec || range; // Если длительность не указана, счет пойдет раз в секунду.
  
  var increment = ( end > current ) ? 1 : -1;
  var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor( ( duration ) * 1000 / range )); 
  
  var id = /#/.test( select ); // Проверка, передали id или класс.
  
  // Если есть id или не указан индекс - берется первый элемент
  // Иначе - элемент по индексу.
  var elem = (id || !index) ? document.querySelector(select) :
                              document.querySelectorAll( select )[index];
   
  if( !elem ){ 
    console.log( 
      "Не найден элемент ('" + select + "')" + (("" + index) ? ("[" + index + "]") : "")
    );
    return;
  }

  var timer = setInterval(function() {  
    current += increment;
    elem.innerText = current;
    if (current == end) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, stepTime);
}
```

```css
.bubu, #bubu {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#bubu {border-color: red;}
```

```html
<div class="bubu"></div>
<div class="bubu"></div>
<div class="bubu"></div>
<div class="bubu"></div>
<div class="bubu"></div>
<div id="bubu"></div>
```

Можно еще сверху добавить условие - если tagName элемента === 'INPUT' или 'TEXTAREA' то вставить elem.value вместо innerText.

P.s. про "почему не работает"...

Если есть условные элементы

```
<div class="bubu" id="moo"></div>
<div class="bubu"></div>
```

Первый элемент можно достать через

```
document.getElementById('moo');
document.querySelector('#moo');
document.querySelector('.bubu');
document.querySelectorAll('.bubu')[0];
document.getElementsByClassName('bubu')[0];
```

Последние два возвращают коллекцию элементов. А у всей коллекции нет того же innerHTML - есть только у его элементов. А эти самые элементы можно достать через числовые ключи. А второй блок можно получить так:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.bubu')[1];
document.getElementsByClassName('bubu')[1];
```

Но предпочтительно использовать querySelector вместо ClassName.

Answer (score 0):

`var obj = document.querySelectorAll(selector);` в результате в obj записывается Node collection из всех найденных элементов. чтобы сделать `obj.innerHTML = current` нужно пройтись циклом или `forEach`

Comment: а зачем использовать querySelectorAll вместо querySelector ?